# golang RabbitMQ exchange direct, amqp

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ using go language.

And I'm going to make real-time comments and like notifications using RabbitMQ.

When user B comments on user A's post,  want to notify user A's screen in real time, "Comments have been created."

Sender

1. `err = channel.ExchangeDeclare("realtime", "direct", true, false, false, false, nil)`
2. `err = channel.Publish("realtime", "like-key", false, false, message)`

Consumer

1. `q, err := channel.QueueDeclare("realtime", true, false, false, false, nil)`
2. `err = channel.QueueBind(queueName, "zxcv", "realtime", false, nil)`

Even though I set the route-key as a part of the bind strangely, I still receive a message from the queue. Can you tell me why?